# what does # do in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to unpick some excel formulas so I can re-engineer the functionality in SQL.

I'm seeing stuff like this:
`=IF(A2#="", 0, A2#)`

I thought it was just a cell reference at first, but then I noticed that rather than changing row by row in the column - e.g.:

`=IF(A2#="", 0, A2#)`

`=IF(A3#="", 0, A3#)`

`=IF(A4#="", 0, A4#)`

There's the exact same formula in ALL the rows in the same column (i.e they all reference cell A2, rather than A3, A4, A5 etc.) BUT the results that are in there pull through as if they **are** referencing the different rows?

Another weird thing is that the font of these formulas is kind of gray in the formula bar, instead of black, and when I click on the formula in the bar, ALL the formulas in the entire column vanish.

Any ideas what's going on?

Ta

Comment: [Spilled range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd)

Comment: Nice one - Thanks.